# Bootstrap pop-over not loading ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, defined, referenceerror

I've been trying for ages a bunch of various solutions but I can't work out why my bootstrap popups arent working.

I'm getting a:
 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
for

```
$(function ()
```

This is my button I want to hover over to show popup:

```
<div class="span3 offset2">
    <a `href="http://automationrecruitment.com.au/apply/">
        <button 
            class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" 
            id="lefty" 
            rel="popover" 
            data-content="this is the content to show" 
            style="min-width:116px; margin:5px;" >
                Apply
        </button>
    </a>
```

This is the scripts I have attached:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

and this is the function call:

```
$(function ()  
{ 
    $("#lefty").popover();  
});
```

I have other bootstrap j.s attached too if you think they may conflict

Comment: Just to check, are you including the jQuery library before you call `$(function ()...` and your reference is actually correct?

Comment: Also `<script language="JavaScript"` is incorrect. Stick to `type="text/javascript"` or if using HTML5 simply `<script src="..."></script>`

Answer (score 3):

The language specified (case sensitive) is incorrect. It causes this not to be interpretted as javascript. Wrong:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Change it to my favorite:

```
<script src="css/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

and it will successfully be interpreted as javascript and define jQuery / $

Comment: Hi,I cant see what I'm doing wrong. atleast now its loading the library and the call is after the library. but im getting a 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

but for what I know it is.

Answer (score 1):

you have to referene jquery **before** referring to the bootstrap.js.
like this:

```
<!-- include jQuery first!!! -->
<script src="/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/lib/bt/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Script tag put the defer attribute before type attribute, defer='defer' one by one in each script and render the page and check the popup functionality.

Some time functionality write in js conflict with each other or not using the updated file of plugins. So in order that two or more files not conflict with each other , place the defer attribute in script tag.

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks.